# is there a solution to run command again prefixed with COMPOSER_DISABLE_NETWORK=1 to make composer run in offline mode?

Tags: composer-php, laravel-8

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.0 example --ignore-platform-reqs
```

> A connection timeout was encountered. If you intend to run Composer
> without connecting to the internet, run the command again prefixed
> with COMPOSER_DISABLE_NETWORK=1 to make Composer run in offline mode.

I tried to create a laravel 8 project with composer. but i had this error whiles installing it.

Comment: which composer version user are using?

Comment: Please follow the steps outlined in the general troubleshooting guideline: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#general  Then [edit] your question and provide the output of `composer diagnose`. And please share if you intended to run it offline or not and what else you have tried since you opened the question. E.g. did running it again work for you?